# How to fix: Lombok builder() method does not seem to be recognised in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, builder, lombok

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. Can somebody please help me out

POM:
[image]

Implementation:
[image]

Using it as below:
[image]

The builder() method does not seem to be recognised. I am using IntelliJ. Is there something that I am missing?

Below are my intelliJ settings:

[image: IntellijSettings - 1]

[image: IntellijSettings - 2]

Comment: did you add the lombok plugin? also, please don't expect us to visit a bunch of external links

Comment: Hey thanks for the suggestion regarding external links. Will keep it in mind. This is my first post. IntelliJ Lombok plugin is already installed in IntelliJ. Thanks

Comment: When you ignore displayed errors from IDE: Does it compile (using mvn clean install) when you add LoginModel.builder.build(); ?

Comment: did u try reimporting project dependencies?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the dependency in the `provided` scope you have to enable the annotation processing (if you are using IntelliJ Idea) and install the [Lombok Plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317-lombok/).

1. ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
       <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
       <version>${lombok.version}</version>
       <scope>provided</scope>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Annotation processing: Navigate to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `Compiler` -> `Annotation Processors` and check `Enable annotation processing`.

   [image]
3. Lombok Plugin: Navigate to `File` -> `Settings` -> `Plugins` and make sure the Lombok plugin is installed.

   [image]
4. Restart IntelliJ Idea - **The most likely missed part :)**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However have already done that.

Comment: See the edit. You should get it work with all in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. It worked now. Though I had all the configurations in place it didn't seem to work. Restarted IntelliJ Twice and that seemed to work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use IntelliJ: You have to install [Lombok Plugin](https://projectlombok.org/setup/intellij) in order to make it work:

1. Go to `File > Settings > Plugins`
2. Click on Browse repositories...
3. Search for `Lombok Plugin`
4. Click on Install plugin
5. Restart IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Thanks. It worked now. Though I had all the configurations in place it didn't seem to work. Restarted IntelliJ Twice and that seemed to work. Thanks for your help!

Comment: It does work that way. I have an issue with lombok installed and annotation processing enabled and dependencies are added to project. This is project specific at some point something happen inside intelljidea with project settings or gradle. Another project in next window with lombok works good.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had used `@Data` and `@NoArgsConstructor`.

To get the `@Builder` to work, I had to add `@AllArgsConstructor`.

`@NoArgsConstructor` seems to invalidate the [all-args] constructor `@Data` adds. So either have just `@Data` or both `@NoArgsConstructor` & `@AllArgsConstructor`

```java
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
public class ThatGreatClassName implements Serializable {
    // code
}
```

OR

```java
@Data
@Builder
public class ThatGreatClassName implements Serializable {
    // code
}
```