# Not working lombok @NoArgsConstructor on a class?

Tags: java, spring-boot, lombok

Class where I create the empty constructor com lombok:
Notes.java:

```
package com.udacity.jwdnd.course1.cloudstorage.modelo;
import lombok.*;
import java.io.Serializable;

@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor(access = AccessLevel.PUBLIC)
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Notes implements Serializable {

    private Integer noteId;
    private String noteTitle;
    private String noteDescription;
    private Integer userId;

    public Notes(Integer noteId, String noteTitle
            , String noteDescription, Integer userId) {
        this.noteId = noteId;
        this.noteTitle = noteTitle;
        this.noteDescription = noteDescription;
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

I use an object of Class Notes.java. In the following file an instance was created applying the empty constructor, but it throws me the error in the image:

```
import com.udacity.jwdnd.course1.cloudstorage.modelo.Notes;
import com.udacity.jwdnd.course1.cloudstorage.services.NoteService;
import com.udacity.jwdnd.course1.cloudstorage.services.UsersService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

import java.util.List;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class InicioController {
    @Autowired
    private UsersService usuarioService;
    @Autowired
    private NoteService notaService;
    @Autowired
    private CredentialService credencialService;
    @Autowired
    private ArchivoService archivoService;

    @GetMapping()
    public String irPaginaHome(Authentication auth, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("noteForm", new Notes());
        Integer idUsuario = usuarioService.obtenerIdusuario(auth.getName());
        List<Notes> notas = notaService.notas(idUsuario);
        model.addAttribute("notas",notas);

        return "home";
    }
}
```

model.addAttribute("noteForm", new Notes());
Can't find empty constructor, what would be the problem.

[image: IDE Intellej, problem the no argument]

Comment: Did you install the lombok plugin in IntelliJ? It is required.

Comment: Only error I see is @AllArgsConstructor annotation. Try to remove it.

Comment: Not install any plugin.

Comment: You most likely didn't enable the annotation processor and install the Lombok Plugin. See my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63151281/3764965 describing these steps.

Comment: Install the plugin and check the configuration, restart the IDE. It doesn't work.

Comment: I removed `public Notes(Integer noteId, String noteTitle, String noteDescription, Integer userId)` since it is covered by `@AllArgsConstructor`, ran `mvn clean verify`, and class shows up in target as expected with 2 constructors and getters/setters. Maybe you should try to comment out `model.addAttribute("noteForm", new Notes());` and run a build?

Comment: Thanks, to solve the problem I had to update the IDE.